# Como retirar caractere especial e ponto de coluna string de um data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
raw_data = {'NAME': ['José L. da Silva', 
                      'Ricardo Proença', 
                      'Antônio de Morais']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['NAME'])
```

Como transformar os nomes da coluna NAME em:

- Jose L da Silva (sem ponto nem acento)
- Ricardo Proenca (sem o cedilha) e
- Antonio de Morais (sem o acento)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `apply()` dos objetos do tipo `Series`. Com ela você pode aplicar qualquer função que retorne algo. Assim, você pode definir uma função de correção e aplicar ela. Por exemplo:

```
def corrigir_nomes(nome):
    nome = nome.replace('.', '').replace('ç', 'c').replace('ô', 'o').replace('é', 'e')
    return nome
```

E depois aplicar na coluna que deseja:

```
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].apply(corrigir_nomes)
```

O resultado vai ser algo como:

```
0      Jose L da Silva
1      Ricardo Proenca
2    Antonio de Morais
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```